# Get WiFi packets before being sent on Android

Tags: java, android, android-wifi

I am trying to make an android app which reads WiFi packets before being sent so I can get the following info:IP, Messages, Pictures and etc. So parents can monitor android phones(Their children's phones). For whatsapp I can do this since messages are stored offline but I not sure about Facebook or other social media. Then I get other problems like what if user goes to a browser. Basically I what to build a app which monitors teens phones for parents. I am a java programmer. **Thank You.**

Comment: What have you done so far to achieve the functionality? Please show some code. Since this question asks for the complete code, getting answers for it will be hard. You could use some Github libraries to achieve your functionalities.

Comment: I never started yet. I'm currently looking is what I what to do is possible. I'll start on it and add the code tday.